# Facebook Login using facebook->getUser() and FB.getUserID()

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

For my website I use a Facebook login. Using the `$facebook->getUser()` function I can redirect a user from the login-page (the home page) to the first page you see when you're logged in.

The result from `$facebook->getUser()` is 0 or the user-id. This value appears to be stored in a Domain Cookie (*not a Session Cookie, so it's not deleted when the browser is completely closed and re-opend*). This is use full because my page doesn't have to connect with Facebook to know the user's id.

The user can however remove all of it's Cookies and thereby let the `$facebook->getUser()` function return a 0 eventhough the user has already accepted the app (which can be found in https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

I also tried to use the following:

```
$accessToken = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->api('/me?access_token=' . $accessToken, 'GET');
```

This however keeps giving me the error `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user`. The `$this->facebook->getAccessToken()` returns the AccessToken from the app insted of the user, so this doesn't help eighter :(

Now my page doesn't know that the users has already been connected with facebook so it opens the *login-page*. Here `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` is loaded and I can make a `FB.getUserID()` request.

**Now the problem and the weird part:**

When `window.fbAsyncInit` function has been finished and the SDK has been loaded Asynchronously

```
 (function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js); }(document));
```

I run the `FB.getUserID()`. This returns Nothing. But about 100-700 miliseconds later it does return the fb-id (if I request it again). So **Javascript somehow got my fb-id from facebook** without having used my domains cookies

When I use the Inspector from Chrome and open Network I can see that, *after everything is supposed to be loaded and finished*, the page `xd_arbiter.php?version=19 (static.ak.facebook.com/connect)` is being requested and loaded.
The same counts for `oauth?client_id=***&response_type=*** (www.facebook.com/dialog)`

It appears that this javascript request **can** get the fb-id from Facebook.

I want to be able to do this with PHP, so the user doesn't unnecessarily have to see the login-page for about 1 or 2 seconds.

I hope I explained it well enough, if not please ask for clarity. I would very much like to have this problem solved! =)

Comment: Since you can not access cookies for another domain, this can not be done server-side.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? So javascript can access cookies from another domain?

Comment: It can make a cross-domain request in the browser.

Comment: So there is no way PHP can ask Facebook for the fb-id of the user that already has accepted the application?? :(

Comment: Only by automatically redirecting to the Facebook login dialog.